# Tiling a Square by Rectangles

Tags: coloring, tiling

I have to prove that you can't create a square with side length $10$ by arranging $25$ rectangles with side lengths $4$ and $1$, where no pair of rectangles may overlap and the whole square must be filled.

If you have a very good design so you always have got $4$ fields on this square but you can't fill them because the $4$ left fields are not a rectangle with the side lengths $4$ and $1$.

Any hints or suggestions for my problem are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint : Color the $10\times10$ square using four colors diagonally. Then the number of squares colored by each color is not all equal.

Comment: Thanks for your hint but I didn't understand it yet. If I colour the square with 4 colours diagonally I will have some rectangles which overlap not all colours but how can I use this information to proove my problem?

Comment: The squares are colored so that all rectangles should have four colors. So all colors should only color 25 squares which is a contradiction since there is a color that colors 26 squares.

Answer (score 1):

Assign integer coordinates to the (centres of) the little squares, in more or less the usual way. The bottom left square is $(0,0)$, the one immediately to its right is $(1,0)$, the next one is $(2,0)$, and so on up to $(9,0)$.  The next row up is labelled $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, and so on.

The sum of the $x$-coordinates of all points is $(10)(45)$, as is the sum of all the $y$-coordinates, for a total of $900$.

Any $1\times 4$ rectangle covers $4$ points the sum of whose coordinates has remainder $2$ on division by $4$. For suppose for example that the rectangle has long side in the horizontal direction. The four $y$-coordinates are all the same, so their sum is divisible by $4$. The four $x$-coordinates are four consecutive integers, and therefore their sum has remainder $2$ on division by $4$.

Now we suppose that $25$ such rectangles cover our $10\times 10$ square, and derive a contradiction.  If $25$ rectangles covered, then the sum of the coordinates of all points would have remainder $2$ on division by $4$. However, $900$ has remainder $0$ on division by $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Color the board as follows

$\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare\\
\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare\\
\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square\\
\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square\\
\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare\\
\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare\\
\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square\\
\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square\\
\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare\\
\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare~\square~\square~\blacksquare~\blacksquare\\$

Notice that a $1\times4$ rectangle placed on the board always covers two black squares and two white squares. Therefore if it's possible to cover the board with $25$ $1\times4$ rectangles, there must be $50$ black and $50$ white squares on the board, which is not the case.